# How to find out the number of CPUs in QT?

Tags: qt

Is there a OS-independent function in QT for this?

There is this `int QThread::idealThreadCount` which returns the ideal number of threads but it does not tell anything about the number of processors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

> Returns the ideal number of threads that can be run on the system.
>   This is done by querying the number of processor cores, both real and
>   logical, in the system.

So it is wrong if you do not consider logical cores to be taken into account, in which case you must use platform-specific API calls.

Comment: Well, if `idealThreadCount()` can query real cores, there must be a function that returns that info as well.

Comment: Yeah, the platform-specific ones.

Comment: If you look into qt sources you will see that it's full with `#ifdef WIN_32` or similar lines - qt does what it does by using different functions on different platforms.

Comment: It's good enough for e.g. jom (replacement for nmake), which uses it to implement a sensible default for the -j parameter. If you are really looking for actual CPUs, use the native OS methods.